# TiKz: how to set distance between two scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm starting to use TikZ. I use it to draw flowcharts. I met the `scope` statement, and I will use it to group my flowchart. For example I have one `scope` aligned at very left of the page.

I wish that the second scope will be aligned 1cm right of first scope.

I've read part of the manual and also other question here. But I didn't find a solution.

How can I obtain that?

Comment: you mean something like `\begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]`?

Comment: This will not work, it means that the two origns of the scopes are distant from 1 cm, not that the distance between the left so called edge of the right scope and the right so called edge of the left scope is 1cm. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Scopes` are drawing environments inside a `tikzpicture`. You cant't align them.
They are usefull as sort of **braces** to draw some stuff with a new `origin` or `scale`, or to `clip` ...

You have to make two different `tikzpicture`s and align them as normal `pictures` ie boxes.

`\scope` and `\endscope` are alternatives to `\begin{scope}` and `\end{scope}` :

> However, if Karl wants to apply graphic options to a local
>   group, he put these commands inside a {scope} environment (Gerda uses \scope and \endscope, Hans
>   uses \startscope and \stopscope). This environment takes graphic options as an optional argument and
>   these options apply to everything inside the scope, but not to anything outside. (pgf manual p. 40)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) ;

\begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)}]
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) ;

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Gerda is a plain TeX user, it's more LaTeXy to use the environment form, I suppose.

Comment: I didn't think about that enventuality. Thank's.